# How to understand GC.stat

Tags: ruby, automation, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and executing GC.stat to check the Garbage Collector data. But I have no idea how to analyse them. Can anyone help in analyzing the result.

Code:

```
p GC.stat
GC.start
p GC.stat
```

Output:

```
{:count=>3, :heap_used=>29325, :heap_length=>29325, :heap_increment=>0, :heap_live_num=>14125, :heap_free_num=>19985518, :heap_final_num=>7}
{:count=>4, :heap_used=>19093, :heap_length=>29325, :heap_increment=>0, :heap_live_num=>6374, :heap_free_num=>13014975, :heap_final_num=>0}
```

Comment: I wonder why you use such an old version of Ruby (1.9.3 is more than seven years old)? Instead of trying to fight memory issues in an outdated Ruby version, I suggest upgrading to Ruby 2.5 with high priority. Memory handling of current Ruby versions has improved a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [`GC`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/GC.html) contains the explanation for literally everything.

I am unsure why would you use the ancient `1.9.3`, but for it you probably need to rewind a documentation to that version.

Comment: Its a legacy framework to test our devices, most of the libraries we use were developed in ruby 1.9.3 to perform actions on raspberry chip sets & to perform tera term commands.